# Проблема с кодировкой при выгрузке из MySQL в С#

Tags: c#, кодировка, mysql

Добрый день

Прошу помощи. Проблема в следующем:
Есть БД в MySQL, MySQL-кодировка - ср1251, делаю выгрузку в C# с помощью MySqlConnection и помещаю в dataGridView но при выгрузке не распознаются русские символы подскажите что делать?

Пробовал уже указывать кодировку и в строке подключения:

```
string conString = "Database=; Data Source=; User Id=; Password=; CharSet=utf8";
```

и запросом после установке соединения

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SET character_set_results = \"utf8\",character_set_client = \"utf8\",character_set_connection = \"utf8\";", sql);
```

и так же запросом

```
"Set NAMES cp1251"
```

Подскажите какие ещё варианты можно попробовать (доступа к ini файлам сервера нет)?

Comment: ср1251 это не utf8.

ср1251 это ср1251


charset=cp1251

Comment: пробовал также и charset=cp1251 (просто выложил не последний фрагмент), результат не меняется - русские символы не распознаются ...

Comment: вот посмотри сам. думаю поймешь, что да как изменить.
гадать можно вечно

http://i.imgur.com/UhhvazL.png

Comment: столкнулся с такой же проблемой, попробуйте мне помогло
как оказалось при выборке из базы данные выбираются в кодировке win-1252

пример почти целиком взят с MSDN

`Encoding enc1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
Encoding enc1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
byte[] byte1252 = enc1252.GetBytes(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
char[] char1251 = new char[enc1251.GetCharCount(byte1252, 0, byte1252.Length)];
enc1251.GetChars(byte1252, 0, byte1252.Length, char1251, 0)
string str1251 = new string(char1251);`

и отдельное спасибо Вам, @NMD за предоставленную табличку

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема, решили вот так

```
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(t.ColumnName as BINARY) USING utf8) FROM t
```

Подробнее можно прочитать тут - http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/